# Single ActiveRecord query to get result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

---

There are two tables:

```
 1. users - {id, name, ...}
 2. users_availabiltiy {id, user_id, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday, ...}

[moday, truesday and other days fields are of boolean type]
```

So, if a user is available for monday, wednesday and thursday, that will have true as its value and the rest will have value as false.
and there is `has_one` relation between these two tables.

Now, the problem is, I need a single ActiveRecord query to get all those users which are available on n days [user inputs the days for which users are returned, e.g. if user enter monday, thursday and friday, our system needs to return all those users which are available for any of these days]
Plus we also need to order the result set based on maximum days matching.

```
[all days matches -> first ranking]
[all days matches-1 -> second ranking] and so on.
```

Note: Database is postgresql and rails version is 4.

This is the easiest approach:

```
input = ["moday","tuesday", "wednesday"]
b = input.map{|day| day+" = true"}
c = b.join(" or ")
b1 = a.map{|day| day+"::int"}
c1 = "*, "+b1.join(" + ")+" as total"
User.joins(:user_availabilty).select(c1).where(c).order("total DESC")
```

Can someone let me know the best and optimized approach apart from this?

Comment: Please show us your effort.

Comment: Based on user input of days, i can manipulate my where condition but problem comes when i need to rank based on input.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest approach:

```
input = ["moday","tuesday", "wednesday"]
b = input.map{|day| day+" = true"}
c = b.join(" or ")
b1 = a.map{|day| day+"::int"} c1 = "*, "+b1.join(" + ")+" as total"
User.joins(:user_availabilty).select(c1).where(c).order("total DESC")
```

Can some one let me know the best and optimized approach apart from this.